# python: retry X times if exception met, exit if not

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, httplib

now it works once if connected successfully, but if exception is met, it 
doesn't retry as I wish, just throwing:

```
Will retry: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

It should return False if all attempts weren't successful and True if at least one returned an answer

Seems there's something complicated with 'while' needed, like

```
for attempt in range(attempts) and while True
```

Here's my code:

```
attempts = 10
for attempt in range(attempts):
   try:
       conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("server:80", timeout=5)
       conn.request("GET","/url")
       r = conn.getresponse()
   except socket.error, serr:
       print("Will retry: %s" % serr)
       conn.close()
   else:
       print("OK")
   finally:
       return False
```

I tried also:

```
for attempt in range(attempts):
   while True:
       try:
```

The same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a counter and a flag inside a while loop.

```
def funct():
    flag = False
    counter = 0
    while True:
        counter += 1
        try:
           conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("server:80", timeout=5)
           conn.request("GET","/url")
           r = conn.getresponse()
           flag = True
           break
        except socket.error, serr:
           print("Will retry: %s" % serr)
           conn.close() 
        if counter>9:
           break
    return flag
```

Comment: hum... i am python newbie, not sure if there is a better way to "encapsulate" the whole "http.conn" steps, so we don't have to use the slightly cumbersome while loop in every func() that i have